# How to cast a multidimensional array to arbitrary type?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, casting

I have the following but it loses the data. I don't understand why. This method works fine on one-dimensional arrays. I am 100% sure that the object in dataContainer value matches the elementType destination.

Note that Color is just a struct with r, g, b. Like you would expect from a Color.

```
public static void TestFillArray()
{
    List<DataContainer> dataContainers = new List<DataContainer>();
    int[] indices = {1, 2, 3};
    dataContainers.Add(new DataContainer(indices, new Color(42, 84, 168, 255)));
    int[] dimensionSize = {2, 3, 4};

    Color[, ,] a = (Color[, ,])GetFilledArray(dataContainers, dimensionSize, typeof(Color));
    Color c = (Color)a[1, 2, 3];
    Debug.Log(c.b);
}

static Array GetFilledArray(List<DataContainer> dataContainer, int[] dimensionSize, Type elementType)
{
    int[] indices = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Array objectArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), dimensionSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataContainer.Count; i++)
    {
        objectArray.SetValue(dataContainer[i].value, dataContainer[i].indices);
        Color storingColor = (Color)dataContainer[i].value;
        Debug.Log(storingColor.r);

    }

    Color c3 = (Color)objectArray.GetValue(indices);
    Debug.Log(c3.r);

    Array castedArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, dimensionSize);
    Array.Copy(objectArray, castedArray, dataContainer.Count);
    //Now data is lost
    Color c4 = (Color)castedArray.GetValue(indices);
    Debug.Log(c4.r);
    return castedArray;
}

//Debug output:
//42
//42
//0
//0
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample input for this method?

Comment: What concrete problem are you trying to solve with this method?

Comment: I will have to condense my code a little to show that. Give me a moment. Concretely I am trying to serialize a multidimensional array into a byte array without using binaryformatter directly (rather use a method to obtain the element's byte[] arrays first)

Comment: I provided some more example code and it shows the data is lost in the copy process. I am building this method because I want to load a list of DataContainer objects into a multidimensional array. It's a way to serialize and deserialize multidimensional arrays of arbitrary  non-binaryformatter serializable types.

Comment: Why can't you use a typical serialization approach?

Comment: @SpencerRuport Well, this may be wrong because I am not very experienced, but what would be a more typical approach to serializing a multidimensional array of a sealed class in an external library that does not implement ISerializable?

Comment: Who makes the external library? If it's a commercial product it's a bit silly that they don't implement any of the standard .Net interfaces. I know getting the library altered isn't always possible but coding up something like what you're doing should be a *desperate* last resort with a plan to either replace the library or phase it out completely. Don't let the toxicity of external code affect your own.

Comment: @SpencerRuport Color is an example of one such non-serializable structs/classes which is part of the UnityEngine.dll that comes with the unity editor. Since the entire product is based on this editor it's a bit difficult to phase out. Personally I don't understand why Unity classes do not implement ISerializable or IComparable because it would be totally trivial to do for 90% of the classes. So yes, it kinda is desperate last resort thing. Maybe it would be better to write serializable/comparable wrappers for all Unity classes?

Comment: You should contact them and ask them if they have any plans to develop it.